# How to remove "[ ]" in the code given below? Expected output is "pollTimestamp"

Tags: java, spring

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String a = "[pollTimestamp]";
        a.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]","");
        System.out.print(a);
     }
}
```

Comment: `a = a.substring(1, a.length - 1)` is probably less error prone

Comment: Also, `replaceAll` returns a new string, it doesn't work in place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your current approach, you need to assign the string back to itself on the LHS:

```java
String a = "[pollTimestamp]";
a = a.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "");
```

However, the following approach might be safer:

```java
String a = "[pollTimestamp]";
a = a.replaceAll("\\[(.*?)\\]", "$1");
```

This way, we only target a term contained within square brackets.  Other types of input would be left alone.

Answer (score 0):

The replaceAll method is attempting to match Non-Alphanumeric Characters.
a.replaceAll() produces a new string, please do another assignment a=a.replaceAll().

```
~ (tilde)
` (grave accent)
! (exclamation mark)
@ (at)

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     String a = "[pollTimestamp]";     
     System.out.print(a.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]",""));

  } 
}
```